# Find two maximum peaks in a histogram according to some condition

Tags: matlab, max, histogram

In the first two images, among all the peaks found using matlab function 'findpeaks',  i have marked in 'red' the  peaks that i want to find, the condition is to find location of two maximum peaks having minimum values, between them.

[image]

For the case of the histograms below, the condition is not satisfied, so, there is no two peaks.

[image]
Any ideas,
Thank you

The histogram values of the tow first images :

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
5,60000000000000
11,4000000000000
17,2000000000000
23,6000000000000
30,4000000000000
33,6000000000000
38
44,2000000000000
47,0000000000000
45,6000000000000
37,4000000000000
27,4000000000000
15,4000000000000
6,20000000000000
2,20000000000000
3,60000000000000
5,40000000000000
7
7,60000000000000
6,20000000000000
4,20000000000000
2,20000000000000
1
1,20000000000000
2,20000000000000
3,60000000000000
5,80000000000000
7,80000000000000
9
9,20000000000000
8,60000000000000
7,20000000000000
5,60000000000000
5,60000000000000
8
12
16,8000000000000
22,2000000000000
25,8000000000000
27,2000000000000
26,8000000000000
25,2000000000000
22,8000000000000
22
22,4000000000000
23,6000000000000
28,2000000000000
34,6000000000000
38,4000000000000
40
37,6000000000000
29
18,8000000000000
10,2000000000000
3,20000000000000
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

0
0
0,600000000000000
1,40000000000000
2,20000000000000
3
3,80000000000000
4
4
4,20000000000000
4,20000000000000
4,20000000000000
4,20000000000000
4,20000000000000
4
4
4
4
4,20000000000000
4,40000000000000
4,60000000000000
4,80000000000000
5,20000000000000
5,40000000000000
5,60000000000000
5,80000000000000
5,80000000000000
5,80000000000000
5,60000000000000
5,40000000000000
5
4,60000000000000
3,40000000000000
2,40000000000000
1,40000000000000
0,600000000000000
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0,200000000000000
0,400000000000000
0,600000000000000
1
1,40000000000000
1,60000000000000
1,80000000000000
3,20000000000000
4,60000000000000
5,80000000000000
6,80000000000000
7,40000000000000
6,80000000000000
6,20000000000000
5,80000000000000
5,40000000000000
5,20000000000000
5,20000000000000
5
4,80000000000000
5
6,20000000000000
7,40000000000000
7,20000000000000
6,80000000000000
5,60000000000000
3,60000000000000
1,40000000000000
0,600000000000000
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

Comment: What's the condition, a mininum threshold? Just use `max` and `>`...

Comment: Please post some sample data as well so that we have something to work with.

Comment: The idea, is to take two peaks, having interval between them contain minimum values of the histogram, i can say near to zero (but i has not a constant threshold)

Comment: Iterate over the peaks and apply your logic to "flag" the ones that satisfy your condition.  This is an algorithm question, not a MATLAB question - or are you expecting us to write all of the code for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-process our data to sort out all values below a threshold:

`data(data<threshold) = 0`

then you can use

`[maxval, index] = max(data)`

to get the maximum and the index. Next you can look for peaks below or equal to the maxval, for example like this:

`data(index) = 0; [maxval, index] = max(data)`

which will give you the next peak (also of equal value) and index of it.

By repeating this process you can then find the indices and values of all the peaks, from largest to smallest.

Answer (score 1):

**Polystep approach**

Step 1, define your threshold and find all values below/above

```
minval = 20;
f = zeros(size(h));
f(h<minval) = 1;
```

step 2, use this code [Split vector in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860008/split-vector-in-matlab) and remove empty cells

```
id = cumsum(f)+1;   
mask = f==0;        
groups = accumarray(id(mask).',h(mask).',[],@(x) {x});
groups(isempty(groups)) = [];
groups=groups(~cellfun('isempty',groups));
```

find all max values

```
maxvals = cellfun(@(x) max(x), groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot you for your answers,
this works very well

```
    S % the Histogram
    TH % threshold
    [pks,locs] = findpeaks(S,'SortStr','descend'); % find peaks
            if size(locs,1)>=2
                for j=1:size(locs,1)-1
                    if locs(j+1)<locs(1)
                        Interval=S(locs(j+1):locs(1));
                    else
                        Interval=S(locs(1):locs(j+1));
                    end 
                    minimum=min(Interval);
                    if minimum<=TH;
                        plot(locs(j+1),pks(j+1),'go','lineWidth',4); 
                        plot(locs(1),pks(1),'go','lineWidth',4); 
                        break;
                    end
                end
            end
```