# MATLAB separating array

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to separate a vector in such a way that I could obtain it in a cell form which includes only same value occurrences. To explain it more, I'm giving an example for it:
e.g My vector is:

```
A=[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0];
B=fun(A);
B={[1 1 1 1 1], [0 0 0], [1 1], [0 0 0 0]};
```

I'm trying to find fun. Is there a function like this in MATLAB or should I do it myself?

Comment: look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860008/split-vector-in-matlab

Comment: another comment user mat2cell ans it's fastier